# Can't call a function C++

Tags: c++

That's a project i made for fun that converts English to morse code
I am still a beginner and i learn c++ by myself so i'm sorry if the question is silly but i don't have anyone else to ask
the problem is about line 17
any idea why it doesn't call it and start over ???
code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
string morse [26] { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-." , "--." , "....", "..",
                ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...",
                "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
char alphabet [26] {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
void convert();
int main (){
convert();
 cout << "\nExit ?(y/n)\n";
 char ans;
 cin >> ans;
 if (ans=='y') return 0;
 if (ans=='n') convert();} //line 17
 void convert () {
string input ;
int i=0 ;
cout << "Enter your text :\n";
getline(cin,input);
for (i;i < input.length() ;i++) {
        string text = input;
    if (text[i] == alphabet[0]) {cout << morse[0] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[1]) {cout << morse[1] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[2]) {cout << morse[2] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[3]) {cout << morse[3] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[4]) {cout << morse[4] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[5]) {cout << morse[5] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[6]) {cout << morse[6] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[7]) {cout << morse[7] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[8]) {cout << morse[8] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[9]) {cout << morse[9] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[10]) {cout << morse[10] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[11]) {cout << morse[11] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[12]) {cout << morse[12] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[13]) {cout << morse[13] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[14]) {cout << morse[14] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[15]) {cout << morse[15] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[16]) {cout << morse[16] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[17]) {cout << morse[17] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[18]) {cout << morse[18] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[19]) {cout << morse[19] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[20]) {cout << morse[20] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[21]) {cout << morse[21] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[22]) {cout << morse[22] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[23]) {cout << morse[23] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[24]) {cout << morse[24] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[25]) {cout << morse[25] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == alphabet[26]) {cout << morse[26] << " ";}
    if (text[i] == ' ') {cout << " / "; }
}

 }
```

Comment: Also look into `std::map`

Comment: You are seemingly to define the `void convert ()` inside of the `main()` function. You have to do that outside (before) main.

Comment: I think I see many syntax errors and I haven't even tried to compile this.

Comment: And `alphabet` and `morse` only have 26 items (indexes 0-25) but you are trying to access index 26

Comment: Please do everyone a favor and add a comment on the line where the problem is so people don't have to count lines.

Comment: it compiles well but when answering by 'n' to exit it doesn't repeat

Comment: The code you've shown above doesn't compile: http://ideone.com/eVYYpL Did you type it by hand or copy&paste?

Comment: copy & paste and it compiles with me well !!!

Comment: sry it missed a curly and i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code, but with regards to why the program doesn't loop, that's because you don't tell it to loop, you only tell it to call convert() a second time.

```
int main (){
    convert();  // first call
    cout << "\nExit ?(y/n)\n";
    char ans;
    cin >> ans;
    if (ans=='y') return 0;
    if (ans=='n') convert(); //line 17
    // program ends
}
```

You have a secondary problem here that you only read one character for `ans`, which means you don't read the "\n" end-of-line, so the `getline()` inside `convert` will think there is an empty line.

You might want to try:

```
int main()
{
    bool quitting = false;

    while (!quitting)
    {
        convert();
        std::cout << "\nExit? (y/N): " << std::flush;
        std::string ans = "";
        std::getline(std::cin, ans);
        if (!ans.empty() && (ans[0] == 'y' || ans[0] == 'Y'))
            quitting = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx man that worked and i have a lot of search to understand how it worked

Comment: i searched but i just want to be sure : does (!quitting) mean (quitting = false) ???

Comment: Yes, `if (quitting)` would mean `if (quitting == true)` so `if (!quitting)` means `if (quitting == false)` (be careful about the double equals)